# How to go back several levels history directory in linux?

Tags: linux

Assume now in `/home/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5`
I use `cd` jump to `/home`
then jump to `/home/dir1/dir2`
i know `cd -` just can go back previous history directory
now i want to go back `/home/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5`,how can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `pushd /home` instead of first `cd /home` and `popd` having all
  that navigation finished.
- Or issue `bash` to start new shell session (or whatever shell you
  are using), do your work and finally type `exit` to close it and return to the previous session.
- And the last and not least, in fact its the coolest solution here: use [console manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen)! A nice, simple to use and powerful tool for all types of the Unix and GNU Linux users.